# can not connect to the pg database hosting on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When try connecting to the PG database I got following error:

> $ heroku pg:psql --app rf1
>       psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
>           Is the server running on host "ec2-184-73-161-119.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

How could I fix it? 
P.s: I am running on a OS X environment and have local pg installed.

Update:

```
heroku pg:info --app rf1
=== SHARED_DATABASE (DATABASE_URL)
Data Size: 312k
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be running one of Heroku's production databases or their new development 9.1 database to be able to connect to the DB from outside;

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql
https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/

Comment: Thanks. I switched to the dev plan and it worked as expected!