# Failed to pull db from Heroku

Tags: database, heroku

Trying pull the database from Hekoku to local but failed.

```
heroku db:pull postgres://root:@localhost/db_name
```

Admittedly, I have no clue how should I construct the url. In the official [site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps) it was `heroku db:push postgres://postgres:mypass@remotehost/mydb` and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841237/heroku-dbpull-not-working) article `heroku db:pull postgres://root:@localhost/db_name` was used. What the user name and password is for?

Anyway, the error message I got was:

```
 Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> TypeError: wrong argument type Sequel::Postgres::Adapter (expected Struct)
```

Having followed the instructions by update the `taps, sequel, and pg` and here is my gem list:

```
rest-client (1.6.7)
sinatra (1.0)
taps(0.3.24)
sequel (3.37.0, 3.20.0)
pg (0.14.0)
```

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace?  It's hard to diagnose the cause of the problem without it.

Comment: Is your application using Activerecord, or are you just pulling this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is no longer relevant now as I have switched from the shared sqlite database to the 9.1 development pg database as been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356775/can-not-connect-to-the-pg-database-hosting-on-heroku). Consequently, instead of using the simple db pull/push , I will use a more sophiscated [pgbackup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) ,which was actually recommended by Heroku.